# Not able to call my api throwing error Disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight

Tags: django, api, ember.js, cors, django-cors-headers

Hey I am new to ember and frontend thing.My backend is designed using django.All my api endpoint ends with " / "(ex:http://example.com/api/feed/).Now when I call this api's from ember app.It send the requests to "http://example.com/api/feed" and leaves the end " / ".

some codes snippet are:

routes.js:

```
return this.store.findRecord('feed');
```

model name is feed.

adapter.js:

```
host:"http://example.com/api",
headers:{'authorization:"abc"}
```

THE ERROR IN CONSOLE IS:

The request was redirected to 'http://example.com/api/feed/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

So it is redirecting to correct api end point but cors is not allowing the requests to happen.

Is there a way to call the api with " / "at end through ember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your `buildURL` method in your adapter. Example for RESTAdapter:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL (modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
    return this._super(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) + '/';
  }
})
```

You could probably also refactor this to use `arguments` instead of explicitly specyfing each param.